# Pass labels for legend in matplotlib from a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I have a csv file with a large amount of data that I am plotting as a scatter plot using pandas and matplotlib. Each data point corresponds to a different specimen I have tested. I wanted to assign each specimen a specific color/marker with the legend indicating the name of the specimen that each point corresponds to. In my csv file I have a column for specimen name, a column for force, a column for displacement, the color I assigned, and marker type. I defined this function below.

```
> def master_plot(df):
>     
> 
>     y = df["Force"]
>     x = df["Displacement"]
>     z = df["Volume"]
>     z1 = z.values.tolist()
>     c1 = df["Color"]
>     c1 = c1.values.tolist()
>     m = df["Marker"]
>     m = m.values.tolist()
> 
>     fig = plt.figure()
>     ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
>     
>     plt.scatter(x,y,c = c1, label = z)    
>     plt.plot( [0,25000],[0,25000])
>     
>     ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
>     
>     plt.title("Force vs Displacement")
>     plt.ylabel("Force") 
>     plt.xlabel("Displacement")
>     
>     
>     plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0), loc='upper left')
> master_plot(df)
```

I can get the scatter plot to output the colors but I just get a list of the different samples in the legend without the color assignment. I have tried including z as an an argument of plt.legend but that results in no output.

[I'd like for the legend to have the appropriate color next to sample name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDLSI.png)

Here is also a snippet of the csv file to show what I am passing through to my function.

```
> Volume,Force,Displacement,,Color,Marker, 
> 1_762-68335-L45-3x,1434.645679,.45,blue,o
> 1_762-68335-L45-3x,952.316311,.23,,blue,v
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things I noticed... the data you provided has extra `,` which I assume is an error. Also, think you have `volume` in your data, but `Name` in code. So, I used your data provided with some additional rows like this

```
>> df
    Name                Force      Displacement Color   Marker
0   1_762-68335-L45-3x  1434.645679 0.45    blue    o
1   1_762-68335-L45-3x  952.316311  0.23    blue    o
2   1_762-68335-L45-4x  2234.645679 0.51    green   v
3   1_762-68335-L45-4x  2982.316311 0.22    green   v
4   1_762-68335-L45-5x  3134.645679 0.44    red x
5   1_762-68335-L45-5x  3052.316311 0.19    red x
6   1_762-68335-L45-6x  4334.645679 0.48    maroon  <
7   1_762-68335-L45-6x  4121.316311 0.20    maroon  <
```

The code is simplified and is as below... I have used matplotlib, as I believe that is the library you prefer. Seaborn would make this a little easier...
Now added code to get the marker. It will pick the first marker from each set of colors in each case

```
def master_plot(df):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    for color in df["Color"].unique():
        ax.scatter(df[df.Color==color].Displacement, df[df.Color==color].Force, 
                  c = color, label = df[df.Color==color].Name.unique(),
                  marker = df[df.Color==color].Marker.to_list()[0])        
    plt.plot([0,25000],[0,25000])
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    plt.title("Force vs Displacement")
    plt.ylabel("Force") 
    plt.xlabel("Displacement")
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0), loc='upper left')

master_plot(df)
```

**Output plot**

[image]

**EDIT - New Req**

If you need a different combination for each entry and you want to show ALL the different entries in the plot, then you can use this data (slightly modified)

```
>>  df
    Name    Force   Displacement    Color   Marker
0   1_762-68335-L45-3x  2434.645679 0.45    blue    o
1   1_762-68335-L45-3x  952.316311  0.23    blue    v
2   1_762-68335-L45-4x  4234.645679 0.51    green   x
3   1_762-68335-L45-4x  6982.316311 0.22    green   <
4   1_762-68335-L45-5x  8134.645679 0.44    red o
5   1_762-68335-L45-5x  10052.316310    0.19    red v
6   1_762-68335-L45-6x  13334.645680    0.48    maroon  x
7   1_762-68335-L45-6x  16121.316310    0.20    maroon  <
```

and this code...

```
def master_plot(df):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    mylabels = []  ##Declare and build an array of labels
    mylabels.append('Diagonal')  ##...with the diagonal line as first entry
    for i in range(len(df)):
        ax.scatter(df.iloc[i,2], df.iloc[i,1], c = df.iloc[i,3], marker = df.iloc[i,4])
        mylabels.append(df.iloc[i,0])
    plt.plot([0,25000],[0,25000])
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
    plt.title("Force vs Displacement")
    plt.ylabel("Force") 
    plt.xlabel("Displacement")
    ax.legend(labels=mylabels, bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1.0), loc='upper left')

master_plot(df)
```

...will give you this plot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edits and helping with the script! If I wanted to add in the marker column would I add an extra argument in ax.scatter ,  marker = df[df.Color==color].Marker?

Comment: Close... but you will need to make it to a `to_list()` and then pick the first element using `[0]` as the df slicing will keep the indices as is. Updated code above. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to make unique marker color combinations. Based off the way the code is written if you define blue as a circle it will always be a circle even if you define blue to be an x later.

Comment: In that case, what is the legend supposed to have? Only the `Name` text? You cant have the color and symbol. Is that ok? There won't be any mapping between the markers+colors to the label as, in the data you provided `1_762-68335-L45-3x` will have a blue circle AND a blue v

Comment: It seems like what I want to do can't be done in matplotlib so maybe I should try seaborn. But yes I was trying to get the legend to display a blue x for 1_762-68335-L45-3x and a blue circle for 1_762-68335-L45-4x for example.

Comment: Ok, one last try :-) Check code under EDIT. This will read each entry and plot it as per color, marker shape. It will also add all the entries into legend. Only catch is that, if you have duplicates, they will also show up in legend. Does this work?

Comment: Yeah duplicates aren't a big deal this is great! I could also make the initial attempt work by exploring deep into the library of colors in matplotlib